# How to enable mTLS between Apache APISIX and etcd?

Tags: apache-apisix

APISIX uses etcd as the configuration center, I have configured and enabled mTLS in etcd for secure data transfer, how do I configure it in APISIX to make it effective?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to prepare a pair of client certificate and private key. Then configure it on APISIX. You can specify them in the config.yaml. The related fields are:

- `etcd.tls.cert`: client certificate
- `etcd.tls.key`: client private key
- `apisix.ssl. ssl_trusted_certificate`: CA certificate to verify the ETCD server certificate